# Infer value of passed property name

Tags: typescript

I'm having a weird problem with generic inferences, which is easier to explain in code then words (so apologies for the vague title).

I have a type for conveying the status of a data request:

```
enum Status {INIT, PENDING, LOADED, ERROR}

type StatusObject = {
  status: Status,
  initiated: boolean,
  error: null | string
}
```

And then various data objects that include a property of this type, e.g.:

```
const obj1 = {
  requestedData: "some data",
  goodStatus: {
    status: Status.LOADED,
    initiated: true,
    error: null
  }
}
```

I have a function that will get passed an object like `obj1` and the key name of the property of type StatusObject for further operations.  Let's say:

```
function checkStatus<T extends string, U extends Record<T, StatusObject>>(
  statusObjectKey: T,
   theObject: U
)
```

In general, this type of signature works.  For example, the following allows the first call but not the second as you'd hope:

```
const obj1 = {
  requestedData: "some data",
  goodStatus: {
    status: Status.LOADED,
    initiated: true,
    error: null
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  data: "some other data",
  badStatus: true
}

checkStatus("goodStatus", obj1). //no error
checkStatus("badStatus", obj2) //error, because obj2 doesn't have a badStatus property of type StatusObject
```

But inside the function itself things don't work as I'd expect.  Namely--

```
function checkStatus<T extends string, U extends Record<T, StatusObject>>(
  statusObjectKey: T,
   theObject: U
) {
  let testStatus: StatusObject
  testStatus = theObject[statusObjectKey] // no error here
  theObject[statusObjectKey] = testStatus // but an error here.  WHY?
}
```

On the second assignment, I don't understand why TS can't tell that `theObject[statusObjectKey]` is of type ObjectStatus (but does seem to be able to tell it in the first assignment).

Can anyone help me understand this?  Is there a better way to type this kind of function?

Here's the code in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gSQHKYCoA0UACgKLYAiOA4kQDIDyAghaRUaQEqcOcC%20AKAFwAngAdgsRMhQMARgCtgAYzhQAvBgFQoKaagBcUpKgLaoASxAW4FpMAAmRuQHsXAG2AIQZncABO-i7%20RuDu7lAAPrpw-lYA5gKCAsouIHpQLooAjBpaOv7AAI5gwHqOFEgIRgBEKC4Qkg5VNb5Q8W4O8CYoRujmOno9Rt0yAHSMLGxtOlY2dnCORrGlM1ABQSFQYe7mgsmp6WpZCgBMef06zYi19Y2ZcAAWAVDXCK3mcghd%20r1QK8AkkIAGZgECqCxpKDKZ7KADWo1QAB48OsAB6LEAONB6OIgeJEACq6Mx2KgnBUwQcKKIiNkihUcAAfEyABTmIYyeRKVQAaWAIiMhAGT2A3MZRkJAgAlPkoJ41Is9HSRr9xapzEq4HS8qL1XAANqc1D6-kiAC6mue%20qNaoZfIF5t1ZW1vygAHp3QB1R4iSxoJ4WNDedaBYIAfiBQhhKgRv1ZNQ6Lh%20PVamRy0pSsLjPQTXxTMjTJ1O0qAA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
Type 'StatusObject' is not assignable to type 'U[T]'
```

That declaration of `let testStatus: StatusObject` actually says that if a subtype of `StatusObject` is assigned to this variable, just treat it like a `StatusObject` instead of the subtype.

---

The problem is that `U[T]` in this function is a more specific type than `StatusObject`.

When a generic extends a constraint (as in `U extends Record<T, StatusObject>`) it's not saying that it needs to be exactly that interface, but whatever is passed in just needs to conform to that interface.

That means that this would be a valid object to pass to that function:

```
const obj1 = {
  requestedData: "some data",
  goodStatus: {
    status: Status.LOADED,
    initiated: true,
    error: null,
    whatever: 'bar' // added extra property
  }
}
```

However, when your function does this:

```
let testStatus: StatusObject
testStatus = theObject[statusObjectKey]
```

You are actually casting that to a more general type. `theObject[statusObjectKey]` is no longer a type that just extends `StatusObject` with that extra `whatever` key, and now is instead exactly a `StatusObject`, which lacks that extra property. The type passed in might require that extra property.

The type has now been *widened* (made more general, less specific). This means that it cannot necessarily be assign back to where it came from.

`U[T]` on the other hand, is a type that *extends* `StatusObject`, and typescript knows whatever else that type is and can check to make sure you're handling it right.

---

So the solution is type your temporary variable as `U[T]`:

```
let testStatus: U[T]
```

Or just let typescript infer it:

```
const testStatus = theObject[statusObjectKey]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gSQHKYCoA0UACgKLYAiOA4kQDIDyAghaRUaQEqcOcC+AKAFwAngAdgsRMhQMARgCtgAYzhQAvBgFQoKaagBcUpKgLaoASxAW4FpMAAmRuQHsXAG2AIQZncABO-i7+RuDu7lAAPrpw-lYA5gKCAsouIHpQLooAjBpaOv7AAI5gwHqOFEgIRgBEKC4Qkg5VNb5Q8W4O8CYoRujmOno9Rt0yAHSMLGxtOlY2dnCORrGlM1ABQSFQYe5rAO4AFvYAbgFGAORyCP7n5oLJqelqWQoATHn9Os2ItfWNmXADgEoN8EK1zFcuvpelAVsAkkIAGZgECqCxpKDKIHKADWo1QAB48OsAB6LEAONB6OIgeJEACqpPJlKgnBUwQcRKI+NkihUcAAfAKABTmIYyeRKVQAaWAIiMhHMgOAkv5RnpAgAlPkoJ41Is9Dz1QBtPAAXSVZTgPLyytVqmN4tQ9rgspEFp0dr5DqdvKlrrlZttVptAHpQwB1A4iSxoQEWNDedaBYIAfgRQixKjx0OFNQ6LihPVamRympS2JzPTzkJ5JZer01QA)

Comment: Excellent explanation, just curious how does that solution compare to [this solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gSQHKYCoA0UACgKLYAiOA4kQDIDyAghaRUaQEqcOcC+AKAFwAngAdgsRMhQMARgCtgAYzhQAvBgFQoKaagBcUpKgLaoASxAW4FpMAAmRuQHsXAG2AIQZncABO-i7+RuDu7lAAPrpw-lYA5gKCAgBmYCCqFi4gUMoAFioA1vAmKAA8eFDAAB5woA5oenEg8QB8ABTmeqXySqoA0sAiRoTmUHAFvSpwRpwqwQ4VRCUyU6qtAgCUWjqeanV6K4bGq4rT5gdwR2iaE8BrcADa3ad9cIMiALoXk2eqz-pZH93kNPhpxsBDoCoAB6GFQPB5CxoZFQEAuKDubLxAJQbxVQLBAB0SSAA)

Comment: That's probably fine, too. If you don't really need `theObject` to be a generic parameter, then that's probably better. But usually it's best to let typescript infer complex types, assuming it gets it right. So either way, I think `const testStatus = theObject[statusObjectKey]` without the cast to `StatusObject` is the way to go.

Comment: very helpful.  is there any way to constrain a generic Record such that Record<T, StatusObject> means T has to _be_ a StatusObject, i.e., extend the Record part (there can be other keys) but the type of index T must be StatusObject?

Comment: You can enforce an exact type with this ugly thing: `T extends U ? U extends T ? T : never : never` But that's complex enough for its own question.